# EXECUTE recognizes a stored procedure, CALL does not

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

When I try to run a stored procedure using EXECUTE, the proc runs fine.  When I use CALL, I get `"ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name"`.  I am connecting directly via toad.  Why can't I use call?

I have tried both of these Calls:

```
CALL(BPMS_OWNER.DAILY_PARTITION_NOROTATE('MIP_TEST',5,5,'MIP_TEST_',5,FALSE,TRUE));
CALL BPMS_OWNER.DAILY_PARTITION_NOROTATE('MIP_TEST',5,5,'MIP_TEST_',5,FALSE,TRUE);
```

The reason I need to use CALL is that our platform parses SQL before we send it to Oracle, which for whatever reason does not support EXECUTE.

Comment: Can you edit your question with your "CALL" statement?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Simply because [`call`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4008.htm#BABDEHHG) *requires* that you add parenthesis, for instance, `call my_proc()`

If I set up a little test:

```
SQL>
SQL> create or replace procedure test is
  2  begin
  3     dbms_output.put_line('hi');
  4  end;
  5  /

Procedure created.
```

And run this several different ways you'll see

```
SQL> exec test
hi

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> call test;
call test
     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name


SQL> call test();
hi

Call completed.
```

Why do you need to use `call`? Isn't `exec`, `execute` and `begin ... end` enough?

---

Based on your update the problem is the booleans, which `call` doesn't seem to support. Creating yet another small procedure

```
SQL> create or replace procedure test (Pbool boolean ) is
  2  begin
  3     if Pbool then
  4        dbms_output.put_line('true');
  5     else
  6        dbms_output.put_line('false');
  7     end if;
  8  end;
  9  /

Procedure created.

SQL> show error
No errors.
```

and running it proves this

```
SQL> call test(true);
call test(true)
          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name
```

I don't quite understand your reasoning behind why you can't use `exec` or `execute` but assuming these are both off limits why not just use a traditional, anonymous PL/SQL block?

```
SQL> begin
  2     test(true);
  3  end;
  4  /
true

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```