# Can't call stored procedure from PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have this simple stored procedure that I wrote and executed in PL/SQL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_sp
IS
     BEGIN
       dbms_output.put_line('Test');
     END;
```

I am trying to call it within PL/SQL like this:

```
CALL test_sp;
```

But I end up getting this error:

```
ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name
```

This is a simple call, is there a syntax error or am I missing some kind of permission?

Comment: possible duplicate of [EXECUTE recognizes a stored procedure, CALL does not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040261/execute-recognizes-a-stored-procedure-call-does-not)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `call` then you will want to include parentheses. The [oracle docs show `call`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4008.htm#BABDEHHG)  using these:

```
call test_sp();
```

Or you can use `exec`:

```
exec test_sp;
```

Or you can just wrap your stored procedure name in an anonymous block:

```
begin
   test_sp;
end;
```