# How to call stored procedure with only OUT parameter?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, call

I have created a stored procedure in Oracle 11g:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE greetings(cnt OUT VARCHAR2) 
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    INTO cnt 
    FROM SYS.all_tables; 
END greetings;
```

but I am unable to call it.

I have tried the following code snippets:

1. `EXEC GREETINGS();`
2. `EXEC GREETINGS;`
3. `CALL GREETINGS;`

Comment: What error do you get? Have you tried `EXEC GREETINGS(null);`

Comment: Error starting at line : 1 in command -
CALL GREETINGS
Error report -
ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name
06576. 00000 -  "not a valid function or procedure name"
*Cause:    Could not find a function (if an INTO clause was present) or
           a procedure (if the statement did not have an INTO clause) to
           call.
*Action:   Change the statement to invoke a function or procedure

iam getting this error for

Comment: Not the source of your issue but a couple of style suggestions.  First, if you have a piece of code that does not update data and merely returns a result, that should really be a function not a procedure.  If it was a function, you could easily `SELECT` it rather than needing to build an anonymous block to call it.  Second, since `cnt` is numeric, you really want to declare the parameter to be numeric rather than a `varchar2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no problem with the procedure body. You can call like this :

```
SQL> var nmr number;
SQL> exec greetings(:nmr);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
nmr
------------------------------------------
306 -- > <a numeric value returns in string format>
```

Oracle doesn't care assigning a numeric value to a string. The execution prints the result directly, but whenever you want you can recall that value of variable(nmr) again, and print as

```
SQL> print nmr
nmr
---------
306
```

Answer (score 2):

The procedure requires one parameter, so - provide it.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE greetings(cnt OUT VARCHAR2)
  2  AS
  3  BEGIN
  4      SELECT COUNT(*)
  5      INTO cnt
  6      FROM SYS.all_tables;
  7  END greetings;
  8  /

Procedure created.
```

One option, which works everywhere, is to use an anonymous PL/SQL block:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_cnt number;
  3  begin
  4    greetings(l_cnt);
  5    dbms_output.put_line(l_cnt);
  6  end;
  7  /
87

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Another one works in SQL*Plus (or any other tool which is capable of simulating it):

```
SQL> var l_cnt number;
SQL> exec greetings(:l_cnt);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print l_cnt;

     L_CNT
----------
        87
```

Comment: when i run Query of greetings procedure, i am getting "Procedure GREETINGS compiled" instead of "PL/SQL procedure successfully completed".  Is this ok?

Comment: Compiled <> completed. Once you have successfully compiled it, you can run it and - if everything goes OK - it'll be successfully completed. Therefore, yes - the first step is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the `call` example, this is explained in [EXECUTE recognizes a stored procedure, CALL does not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12040261/230471). It's not obvious from the syntax documentation but it does require brackets, so it is (rather unhelpfully) rejecting the whole thing and giving the impression that `greetings` is the problem, when actually it is not:

```
SQL> call greetings;
call greetings
     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name
```

while using the mandatory brackets gets you the real issue:

```
SQL> call greetings();
call greetings()
     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GREETINGS'
```

As others have pointed out, you are missing the parameter.

```
SQL> var n number
SQL>
SQL> call greetings(:n);

Call completed.

SQL> print :n

         N
----------
       134
```

[`execute`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/EXECUTE.html) is just a handy SQL*Plus shortcut for the PL/SQL block `begin xxx; end;` which is less fussy about brackets and gives the same error message with or without them.

([`variable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/using-scripts-in-SQL-Plus.html#GUID-B52D6F2E-A28A-48B6-B73F-6A9D018BD107) and [`print`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/using-scripts-in-SQL-Plus.html#GUID-9867449B-2217-4477-9DF2-732989D6BCDE) are SQL*Plus commands and may not be supported in other environments.)

Comment: i am newb here,

when i tried

var n number 
call greetings(:n);



i need to enter Binds 

and i am getting 01008 not all variables bound

Comment: `var(iable)` is a SQL\*Plus command, so if you want it to work in SQL Developer or Toad or something else you will need to check how to handle it in that. What tool are you using?

Comment: I am using Oracle SQL Developer